# calling script php from Ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Excuse me, practices need to call a php script from ruby.

This will make the scipt php function to insert a record in two different databases out of my local server.

For example:

After a user registers need to register the same record in two external databases, and had thought of doing it with a php script with ruby because I have no idea, because they mistakenly used a database architecture decentralized, and I should make many modifications in the codigoa INSERT INTO only do one triple, one at a local database and two more to external databases.

I hope I have expressed correctly.

Thanks for your time and your answers

---

excuse me, practices need to call a php script from ruby.

This will make the scipt php function to insert a record in two different databases out of my local server.

For example:

After a user registers need to register the same record in two external databases, and had thought of doing it with a php script with ruby because I have no idea, because they mistakenly used a database architecture decentralized, and I should make many modifications in the codigoa INSERT INTO only do one triple, one at a local database and two more to external databases.

I hope I have expressed correctly.

Thanks for your time and your answers

Answer (score 0):

You should phrase your question more precisely. You can either use the standard Ruby system execution methods to run the PHP interpreter, or you can use the HTTP library to request the PHP script from the webserver, hence running it.

Or do you have a different question?